# Automatic mapping seems to not like 'Name' fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a model that looks like this.

```
class Aspect {
  Guid Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
  string Description { get; set; }
  // multiple other properties
}
```

In my View (ASP.NET MVC 3.0) I am trying to use the KnockoutJS mapping plugin. I call upon it like this. (*Html Helpers listed beneath*)

```
// attempt to bind any data we received from the server
var serverData = @Html.Interpret(Model);
// auto map the knockout attributes from the server data
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(serverData);
// apply the knockout binding to the viewModel
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#__frmAspect")[0]);
// attach the jquery unobtrusive validator
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#__frmAspect");

viewModel.Save = function() {
    // we will try to send the model to the server.
    ko.utils.postJson(
        $("#__frmAspect").attr('action'), { model: ko.toJS(viewModel) }
    );
};

// bind the submit handler to unobtrusive validation.
$("#__frmAspect").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = viewModel.Save;
```

For the most part, this actually works. However, for whatever reason, it does not like the `Name` field.

It **creates** it, mind you. If I place a breakpoint at `postJson` in the knockout.js file, I can sit there and see that the `ko.observable()` **does exist**. It just is not getting set by the input field.

Can anyone tell me why this might be?

My Html Helpers:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc {
    public static class KnockoutHelpers {
        public static MvcHtmlString Interpret<TModel>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, TModel model) {
            return new MvcHtmlString(model.ToJson());
        }
    }

    public static string ToJson ( this object item ) {
        return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer( ).Serialize( item );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like we got this solved on the KO forums.  Autocomplete was not firing the change event on the Name field.

Defined the data bind like:  `data-bind="value: Name, valueUpdate: 'blur'"` to make this work.

Comment: Thanks... I meant the actual thread though - I know the forums but couldn't find a thread discussing this when I searched. Do you have a link to that? I have some related issues and am interested in seeing what exactly was discussed.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question.  I am sure that you could find the forums without a link :)   Here is that discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/knockoutjs/PPXS86CLbdE/discussion